# Uso o delphi 10.4 e qdo aperto a tecla F7 pra debugar aparece varias abas ( SysInit, CPU, System... e outras e não consigo debugar. Como resolver?

Tags: delphi, debug, delphi-10, windows-10, cpu

Ao debugar meus programas em delphi 10.4 pela tecla F7, aparecem varias abas (System, CPU, SysInit e outras que não permitem entrar no debug do código fonte em si! Meu Windows é windows 10! Alguém sabe como resolver isso? no delphi 7 rodava o debug normal, mas troquei de  SO e de ide e deu esse erro.

Comment: Use F8 para prosseguir para próxima linha quando debuga código, F7 vai entrar na função da linha.

Comment: Eu ja tentei a F8 pra debugar! Até vai de linha em linha mas somente ate a linha Application.Run ai o programa executa e não exibe mais as linhas de codigo! Por exemplo se eu clicar num button que executa uma função ele não entra no código pra debugar. Como faço pra resolver isso?

Comment: Você adiciona um break point no OnClick do Butto. Verifique se não vai ficar um X sobre o ponto vermelho do break point, se ficar, quer dizer que o Break Poijnt não vai ser alcançado e a IDE não vai parar nesse  caso você pode tentar remover e adicionar de novo, adicionar o breakp point em outra linha ou em último caso reiniciar a IDE.

Comment: Então, da forma que vc indicou dá certo, mas não tem como fazer o debug sem precisar dos breaks @Diego_F?  Tipo como era no DELPHI 7? Porque durante pesquisas sobre o assunto vi que outras pessoas fazem o debug sem precisar de breaak point!  Sua ajuda já abre o caminho, mas se pudesse me tirar essa dúvida  ficaria perfeito! Abraço;

Comment: Eu normalmente executo meus projetos usando F9(não sei se é este que está usando) se usar F7 ele começa com o debug desde a primeira linha do source file.
Agora se tem como debugar um botão, por exemplo, sem fazer uso de break point, desculpe, mas eu desconheço.

Comment: Mano @Diego_F. vc ajudou bastante! Com sua dica já consigo debugar meus projetos!  O que estranhei é que no delphi 7 fazia o debug pelo F7 sem precisar colocar um break, tipo era só clicar num objeto do form  e  sair apertando o F7 pra ir linha a linha!  Tou fuçando agora o DELPHI 10, por isso as dúvidas! Mas valeu amigo!

Comment: Mano @Diego_F, amigo preciso de mais uma ajuda! Nem sei se pode ser por esse mesmo tópico, mas é que nã tou consguindo gravar na tabela que uso! tipo o usuario clica num botao e contabiliza +1 no campo do serviço inducado!  fazendo o debug o campo recebe o valor, aparece no db grid a altrração, depois  dou o .post. Mas qdo abro a tabela novamente não ta salvo o registro! Volta sempre ao que era antes Uso um DM.FDTcONECTION + TFDTTABLE. Podes me ajudar?

Comment: Acredito que seja necessário outro tópico, pois é um problema diferente.
Quando for criar lembre-se não postar código em imagens, detalhar bem seu problema e o que já fez para tentar resolver, além de colocar um MVC.
Para mais detalhes o [Guia de Sobrevivẽncia Resumido](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8089/guia-de-sobreviv%c3%aancia-do-sopt-vers%c3%a3o-curta?noredirect=1&lq=1) e o [Manual de como não fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%c3%83o-fazer-perguntas?noredirect=1&lq=1) podem te ajudar.

Comment: O movimento de perguntas com a tag Delphi não é muito ativo no Stack Overflow em Português  se comparadas a tecnologias voltadas para Web, por exemplo, então dependendo da sua urgência talvez seja melhor perguntar direto no Stack OverFlow em Inglês mesmo.

Comment: oi! Resolvi da seguinte maneira: criei um campo na tabela e coloquei como indice so pra ter uma key! masn na hora de mostrar a atualização não exibo esse campo! é uma gambiarra mas deu certo!

Answer (score 0):

Por padrão o delphi vem configurado como teclas de debug
F7=stepinto
F8=stepover
F9=continue

Quando usar o F7? quando você está com o cursor parado em cima de uma function ou procedure e você quer ver o que será executado ali dentro, ai nesse caso ele te joga pra dentro da rotina.

Quando usar o F8? Quando você precisa passar passo a passo dentro de uma mesma rotina, ignorando o conteúdo de functions ou procedures que são executados naquele bloco de código, mantendo o foco no mesmo. Ou ainda você pode usar o F8 pra chamar o debug da aplicação passando pela inicialização do app.

Quando usar o F9? O uso do F9 no processo de debug ele ignora todos os outros passos que vem a seguir e retoma o fluxo normal de execução do debug. Ou ainda quando você precisa chamar o debug da aplicação e não quer passar pela inicialização do app.

Existem alguns casos que esse problema reportado por você podem acontecer, principalmente quando em seu código existe chamadas para bibliotecas, ou packages compiladas, aonde o debug deixa de ser possível e a partir dai o delphi começa a monitorar a instancia do seus dados que foram enviados para essa rotina.